# Fibonacci Sum in (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, netbeans, fibonacci

recently I have been working on an assignment to find the fibonacci sum of a number (user input, positive integer) in recursive form, for example (output is):
    9 = 8 + 1
    14 = 13 + 1 
    30 = 21 + 8 + 1
    and so on.
So far, I have made the recursive function to calculate the actual fibonacci numbers (such as 8 and 1 in the sum of 9), it looks like this :

```
static long[] f = new long[50];

static long fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) { //base case
        return 1;
    }
    if (n < f.length) {
        if (f[n] != 0) {
            return f[n];
        }
        return f[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

My assignment gives me this as a hint:

Hints:
Re-cast the theorem as
n = fj + (n - fj )
This suggests a recursive solution.

and with that, I have currently come up with this:

```
static void fibSum(int n) 
{ 
    System.out.print(n + " = ");
    for(int i = 0; i >= 0 ; i++)
    {
        if(n - (fib(i)) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(fib(i));
        }
        else if(n < (fib(i)) && n > (fib(i-1)))            
        {
           System.out.println(fib(i-1) + " + "); 
        }
    }  
}
```

My output goes as far as [entering for example, 9 as the user input] '9 = 8 +', and with that said, my question for all of those who are reading this (and thank you for getting this far!) is why I am not getting the last number (1) in the broken-down sum, and is my solution considered recurisve, as it really does not follow the format that I have seen in past examples, and in the fib() method that I wrote. I did not know how to implement printing the plus signs through that format.
Here is my main method for reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer number: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    fibSum(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seems to have various issues in your function fibSum:

1. Your For loop does not have an end. (while i is positive, increment i.)
2. You can store: fib(i) in your for loop to avoid multiple calculations.
3. You don't handle every cases on your if/else condition.

Exemple:

```
n = 2. 
fib(0) = 1
if(2 - 1 == 0) => false
if(2 < 1 && 2 > fib(-1)) => false && error.
// Displays nothing. Should display: 2 = 1 + 1
```

Comment: I thought that due to the fib function's base case n<=1, it handles cases such as fib(-1) and returns it as 1? perhaps I am wrong, currently trying to go through the things you mentioned to try and find and fix 'em all.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, this time using a while loop. No matter how many times I tried fixing the for loop, I ran into issues with my output, so I used a boolean variable and simply made it false once I reached n = 0.